# Форматирование кода в webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, форматирование

Есть комбинация <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Форматирует красиво, но гораздо удобней лично для меня было бы не просто пробелы проставить, а, например, выровнять переменную и значение в две колонки.
Например:

```
let num1        = 1;
let number2     = 2;
let superNumber = 3;
```

Может есть плагин какой? Или шторм сам может справиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WebStorm 2017.1.2 эта настройка находится в *File*->*Settings*->*Editor*->*Code Style*->*JavaScript*. Далее нужно выбрать вкладку *Other*. На левой панели раздел *Align 'var' statements and assignments*. Ниже нужно выбрать *Align multiple 'var' statements and assignments*

В WebStorm более новых версий
*File*->*Settings*->*Editor*->*Code Style*->*JavaScript*->*Wrapping and Braces*->*Variable declaration*->*Align* в значение *When multiline*

Comment: не вижу вкладки... настройки вы великолепные открыли для меня. Но вкладку не вижу

Comment: Видимо версии под Linux и Windows различаются. Вот [мой](http://www.picshare.ru/view/8231997/) скрин

Comment: и там нету)) я под лином тоже сижу

Comment: Впроверь версию webstorm

Comment: моя версия 2017.2.1

Comment: Действительно, скачал новую версию и вкладка _Other_ там исчезла. Сейчас эта нстройка находится во вкладке _Wrapping and Braces_ в самом низу _Variable declaration_ -> _Align_ нужно установить в _When multiline_